# Can I detect if someone is using a serial port sniffer?

Tags: serial-port, usb, sniffer

I am working on a project to communicate with devices plugged into USB using serial communications.  I know that this type of software product is often hacked using serial port/ usb sniffing.  How can I prevent this from happening to my software.

Comment: What are you trying to protect?  The communications or some "secret" that exists in the software or on the USB device (for example, a piece of data that will allow the software to run)?

Answer (score 2):

You can discourage software sniffing using nasty techniques like kernel modules.

However, someone can physically place a hardware sniffer between your computer and your device. There's no way for you to stop that if the dongle is in the user's hands.

You can slow them down with heavy encryption, but someone running your program on their computer has full access to any encryption keys in memory.

Comment: Eh, you snagged me... fishing for a Revival badge, are you? ;-)